# Geometric location of points for which the distance to $2x-y+2z-6=0$ is twice the distance to $x+2y-2z+3=0$

Tags: analytic-geometry

how can I find the geometric location on $\mathbb{R}^3$ for which the distance to $2x-y+2z-6=0$ is twice the distance to $x+2y-2z+3=0$ ?

The equation I'm used to using to compute the distance from point to plane is

$$
d = \frac{| \ Ax + By + Cz + d \ |}{|\vec{n}|}
$$

if $\vec{n}$ is the normal vector of the plane and $P = (x,y,z)$ the point.

The answer should be two planes, but I'm having a hard time starting the exercise. Any tips are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: do you know how to compute the distance of a point from a plane?

Comment: You might try this in 2D to see what happens.

Comment: @uniquesolution yes I'm used to use the formula above that I just posted. Can I use it?

Comment: I'm still not sure. Can you help me go further?

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment,
but it's too long,
so I'm making it an answer.

To get an idea of what happens,
I'm going to look at the
simplest possible versions of this.

For 2D,
consider the lines
$L: x=0$
and
$M: y=0$.

If a point
(in the first quadrant)
$(x, y)$
is twice as far from $L$
as from $M$,
then
$x = 2y$,
so this is a straight line.

For 3D,
consider the two planes
$L: x=0$ and $M: y = 0$.
If $(x, y, z)$
is twice as far from $L$
as from $M$,
then
$x = 2y$
and this is a plane
through the line
$x=y=0$.

So,
the result seems plausible.

I'll let someone else
to the actual algebra.

Comment: I'm still not sure. Can you help me go further?